# Symfony2 entity field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-2.1

I developed an application with Symfony2 and I have problem.

I have User Entity class, in this class I have:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProperty", mappedBy="user")
*/
protected $properties;
```

and

```
/**
 * Add properties
 *
 * @param Flashwand\UserBundle\Entity\UserProperty $property
 * @return User
 */
public function addProperties(\Warski\Flashwand\UserBundle\Entity\UserProperty $property)
{
    $this->properties[] = $property;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove properties
 *
 * @param Flashwand\UserBundle\Entity\UserProperty $propertie
 */
public function removeProperties(\Warski\Flashwand\UserBundle\Entity\UserProperty $property)
{
    $this->properties->removeElement($property);
}

/**
 * Get properties
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getProperties()
{
    return $this->properties;
}
```

in UserProperty class I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="properties")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=55, nullable=true)
 */
protected $phone = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="fax", type="string", length=55, nullable=true)
 */
protected $fax = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
 */
protected $company = null;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="job_description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $job_description = null;
```

and now, I'm trying to biuld registration form with Username, Email, Password and Company namme from UserProperty.

When User fill fields i want to create new user and propery which gave.

My form builder looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'Email',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
    ));
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'invalid_message' => 'Password don\'t match.',
        'first_options'  => array(
            'label' => 'Password', 
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
        ),
        'second_options' => array(
            'label' => 'Retype password', 
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
        ),
    ));
    $builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Firstname',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
    ));
    $builder->add('lastname', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Lastname',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
    ));
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'Email',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
    ));
    $builder->add('properties', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'FlashwandUserBundle:UserProperty',
        'property' => 'company',
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'label' => 'Company',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
    ));
}
```

I want to create field "company" like a text, not select or radio button.
Can I do that, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

just look in to Data Transformers http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html in this Scenario they receive content by a string (in your case the company name) but of course instead of throwing an error you can just as well create an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Should you create a [Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

like ex:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PropertiesType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('company')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Flashwand\UserBundle\Entity\UserProperty',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'properties';
    }

}
```

And change your form builder

```
$builder->add('properties', new PropertiesType(), array(
    'label' => 'Company',
    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now, I have something like this, but I don't know, what to do in Controller, how can I add User to database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [property_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) for that. BTW I see that you mistake something with OneToOne relation. If this is OneToOne why user.properties are collection/array and User entity have addProperty/removeProperty method? [Here](https://gist.github.com/63468c95bd1182725c22) I prepared for you some small example how I will resolve that (gist).